Lightning data table not displaying data
Lightning table data is not displaying
Apex controller
public class SfdcSupplierTaxController {
@AuraEnabled

public static List <Tax_Registration__c> getRecords(String accountId) {
   
    List<Tax_Registration__c> TaxList = [SELECT Id, Account__c,Country__c,TaxId_Type__c,Tax_Registration__c
                                from Tax_Registration__c WHERE Account__r.Id = :accountId LIMIT 5];
   
    return TaxList;


}
}

Aura Component:
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="SfdcSupplierTaxController">

<aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" />

<aura:attribute name="isPrimaryContact" type="Boolean" default="false" />

<aura:attribute name="supplier" type="Account" />

<aura:attribute name="user" type="User" />

<aura:attribute name="TaxList" type="Tax_Registration__c[]" />

<aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchAcc}" />

<lightning:card class="slds-theme_default">

    <aura:set attribute="title">

        <span class="slds-text-heading_medium">{!$Label.c.S360_Tax_Registration}</span>

    </aura:set>

    <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-var-m-left_medium headingdiv">

        <p><i>{!$Label.c.S360_Tax_Description}</i></p>

    </div>

    <aura:set attribute="actions">

        <lightning:button aura:id="newSite" iconName="utility:adduser" iconPosition="left" label="{!$Label.c.S360_Add_Tax_Registration}" variant="brand" />

    </aura:set>

    <div class="slds-text-body_regular" style="height: 100px">

        <lightning:datatable data="{! v.TaxList }" columns="{! v.mycolumns }" keyField="Id" hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>

    </div>

</lightning:card>

</aura:component>

Controller JS:
({

fetchAccHelper : function(component, event, helper) {

    component.set('v.mycolumns', [

        { label: 'Country', fieldName: 'Country__c', type: 'text' },

        { label: 'Tax Id Type', fieldName: 'TaxId_Type__c', type: 'text' },

        { label: 'Tax Registration Number', fieldName: 'Tax_Registration__c', type: 'text' }, // Change type to 'text'

        { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Placeholder', type: 'text' }

    ]);

    let supplierId = component.get("v.accountId");

    let action = component.get("c.getRecords");

    action.setParams({ accountId: supplierId });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

        let state = response.getState();

        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            let result = response.getReturnValue();

            console.log('Returned Records:', result); // Debug output

            component.set("v.TaxList", result);

        } else {

            console.log('Error:', response.getError()); // Debug output for errors

        }

    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}

})


Are you seeing any error message?
